# Altering data in JavaFX StackedBarChart keeps pushing startingposition up

Tags: java, javafx

I was playing around with the Oracle examples for StackedBarCharts from https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

When I start my program everything looks fine 
[image: Start] , but whenever I remove values and replace them the new bars start above zero like 
[image: this].

Curious about this behavior I looked for solutions online, and came across another sample code from [Java-Buddy](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/03/javafx-2-update-stackedbarchart.html). His example code has TextEdits where you can change values for the chart, altering those values gives me the same "error"(e.g Bars going from 120 to 200 instead of 0 to 80, though in his video showing how it works he does not run into the same issue).

If anyone is able to explain to me what I'm doing wrong that would be appreciated.

Here's the code I'm working on right now(It has some other issues as well).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TablesAndStuff extends Application {
  Scene scene;
  final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
  final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
  StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc = new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series4 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series5 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series6 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series7 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

int[] leagues = new int[7];
int[] A = new int[] { 207, 1958, 7293, 11484, 17234, 20851, 13508 };
int[] B = new int[] { 283, 2189, 9392, 14959, 20821, 21125, 10148 };
int[] C = new int[] { 222, 1484, 5524, 9658, 17552, 25750, 16375 };

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    setUpLeagues();
    stage.setTitle("Stacked Bars");
    sbc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String> observableArrayList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")));

    yAxis.setLabel("Value");
    series1.setName("1");

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", A[0]));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", B[0]));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", C[0]));

    series2.setName("2");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 1985));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 2189));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 1484));

    series3.setName("3");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 7293));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 9392));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 5524));

    series4.setName("4");
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 11484));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 14959));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 9658));

    series5.setName("5");
    series5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 17234));
    series5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 20821));
    series5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 17552));

    series6.setName("6");
    series6.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 20851));
    series6.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 21125));
    series6.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 25750));

    series7.setName("7");
    series7.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 13508));
    series7.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 10148));
    series7.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 16375));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(sbc);
    // root.getChildren().add(btn);
    // StackPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

    sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4, series5, series6, series7);
    sbc.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            /*
             * Todo: Figure out a better way of detecting mouseclicks.
             * (Adding handler directly to series does not seem to work,
             * name of series clicked shows up in the targets toString but have not
             * yet found a direct property for it
             * 
             */
            if (arg0.getTarget().getClass().equals(Region.class)) {
                Region r = (Region) arg0.getTarget();
                if (r.toString().contains("series1")) {
                    changeScene(stage, 1);
                }
                if (r.toString().contains("series2")) {
                    changeScene(stage, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
//Tried clearing and readding data in several different ways, still need 
private void changeScene(Stage stage, int i) {
    // stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,
    // yAxis)));
    series1.getData().clear();
    series2.getData().clear();
    series3.getData().clear();
    series4.getData().clear();
    series5.getData().clear();
    series6.getData().clear();
    series7.getData().clear();
    // sbc.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 200));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 250));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 225));

    // Clearing SBC then re-adding any series results in
    // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added
    // sbc.getData().clear();
    // sbc.getData().add(series1);
    // sbc.getData().add(series2);

}

private void setUpLeagues() {
    leagues[0] = 736;
    leagues[1] = 6056;
    leagues[2] = 24370;
    leagues[3] = 40666;
    leagues[4] = 63922;
    leagues[5] = 77155;
    leagues[6] = 44946;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sbc.setData() again to set it to only the series you want to display and resync the collection of series.

eg.

```
private void changeScene(Stage stage, int i) {
    series1.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("A", 200),
        new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("B", 250),
        new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("C", 225)));
    sbc.setData(FXCollections.singletonObservableList(series1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The resync helped. The one thing I didn't like with that solution was that it removed the buttons at the bottom of the chart so that I could no longer switch between datasets. To solve that I cleared the series and used setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(allSeries)). Not very elegant, but seems to work.